# Modifying Firebase - Dynamic Link's App Preview Page

Tags: firebase, translation, firebase-dynamic-links

Has anyone tried modifying this app preview page from Firebase?

We've setup a dynamic link for one of our apps and enabled a preview page. We want the default string to get translated. Is there a way to translate the sentence:

> Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this
> page.

and the text on the button

> OK

from this app preview page from Firebase?

[image]

Comment: I think they could translate it into understandable English to begin with. I'm a developer and have no idea what that means. Optimizing UX and conversion rates and what not, and then you are stuck with this.

Answer (score 3):

I raised this question to the support team of Google Firebase (Case 10159315) - here is their reply:

> Currently, localization of the text displayed isn't supported and
> there seems to be no way to customize it yet. I appreciate your
> feedback, so I've filed a request to support localization in the app
> preview page. For now, I can't guarantee any details or timeline, but
> please keep an eye on our release notes for any Firebase updates.

So that's the (unfortunate) answer to that question

Comment: Thanks for raising this up to them @nanz

Answer (score 1):

To change these preview details you need to provide the below details to update it.

When you provide social metadata in your Dynamic Link, the app preview page displays the title, description, and image you specified instead, as well as your app's name and icon. For example:

**DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters**

**title**   *The title to use when the Dynamic Link is shared in a social post.*

**descriptionText** *The description to use when the Dynamic Link is shared in a social post.*

**imageURL**    *The URL to an image related to this link. The image should be at least 300x200 px, and less than 300 KB.*

So this will help you to set a custom title and description on your app preview page.

**Ref Link:**

[Generate Link Preview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews)

[Create Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I don't think this handles the label on the checkbox and the button text though. We specifically need to translate these texts:

Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this page.

plus the text on the button: OK

Comment: @arvinq we have the same issue. Could you find any solution so far?

Comment: @nanz Haven't found any solution on this.. if you do find any solution, please post it here so it can help other people looking for answers.. :)