# How to customise preview firebase page, when using firebase dynamic links?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

[image: This page]

I try to customise preview page, to make it more beautiful

Comment: Please be more specific about your query rather than being generic so the community can help you better an others can also benefit from this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry) I want to change proportion of image, add big button (like "get app"), change font, color etc

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your customisation options are very limited on Firebase Dynamic links.

You can modify the preview page by having Social Metadata to generate rich previews to create something like below

This image has been taken from Firebase Dynamic Link Doc

[image]

Additionally, you can refer the below links for more info

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69521688/5133769
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews